# Distributing files using AWS (from AWS to local)

Tags: amazon-web-services

we start working with AWS and are currently making our first steps. We picked a first application we want to move to AWS and maybe even re-build using AWS cloud technology. 
Application is connecting to a database and based on some query it is going to create documents. Once created it needs to distribute those documents to local file shares to ahve them on site in case network goes down etc...
Wondering what might be a good approach for getting documents from AWS back to our local fileshares? Would be great if someone could point me into a good direction!
Greetings

Comment: You want your AWS application to automatically send files to your *localhost*? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Not my localhost - some locations on our on-premise filesystem. Idea is to push files out of AWS using FTP or something like that

Comment: try some `cURL` with file attachment

Comment: thx for that hint! u see any chance using lambda? So once a new document e.g. gets added to S3 bucket, distribute it?

Comment: Have you considered the [AWS storage gateway, file gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/faqs/)?